# How to convert pine script stdev to python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pine-script, ta-lib

I'm trying to convert pine script stdev to python code but it seems I'm doing it wrong
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_stdev

Pine script:

```
//the same on pine
isZero(val, eps) => abs(val) <= eps

SUM(fst, snd) =>
    EPS = 1e-10
    res = fst + snd
    if isZero(res, EPS)
        res := 0
    else
        if not isZero(res, 1e-4)
            res := res
        else
            15

pine_stdev(src, length) =>
    avg = sma(src, length)
    sumOfSquareDeviations = 0.0
    for i = 0 to length - 1
        sum = SUM(src[i], -avg)
        sumOfSquareDeviations := sumOfSquareDeviations + sum * sum

    stdev = sqrt(sumOfSquareDeviations / length)
```

Python code:

```
import talib as ta
def isZero(val, eps):
    if abs(val) <= eps:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def SUM(fst, snd):
    EPS = 1e-10
    res = fst + snd
    if isZero(res, EPS):
        res += 0
    else:
        if not isZero(res, 1e-4):
            res = res
        else:
            res = 15
    return res

def pine_stdev(src, length):
    avg = ta.SMA(src, length)
    sumOfSquareDeviations = 0.0
    for i in range(length - 1):
        s = SUM(src.iloc[i], -avg.iloc[i])
        sumOfSquareDeviations = sumOfSquareDeviations + s * s

    stdev = (sumOfSquareDeviations / length)*(sumOfSquareDeviations / length)
```

What am I doing wrong? And why SUM function returns 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trading View has made a mistake in the code on the site.
The number "15" should be written as "1e-5".
You can use this code:

```
def SUM(fst, snd):
    EPS = 1e-10
    res = fst + snd
    if isZero(res, EPS):
        res = 0
    else:
        if not isZero(res, 1e-4):
            res = res
        else:
            res = 1e-5
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out using numpy and using vectorization which is faster than doing a for loop for every bar

I start at length - 1 because before length is just nan values so you don't need to work with those

on tradingview stdev website they say
na values in the source series are ignored; the function calculates on the length quantity of non-na values.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta.stdev

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def sma_calc(source: np.array, length: int):
    arr = np.cumsum(source, dtype=np.float_)
    arr[length:] = arr[length:] - arr[:-length]

    sma = np.full_like(source, np.nan)
    sma[length - 1 :] = arr[length - 1 :] / length

    return sma

def stdev(source, length):
    avg = sma_calc(source=source, length=length)

    sum_square_dev = np.full_like(avg, np.nan)

    looper = length - 1

    for i in range(looper, avg.size):
        res = source[i - looper : i + 1] + -avg[i]
        res_2 = np.where(np.absolute(res) <= 1e-10, 0, res)
        sum = np.where((np.absolute(res_2) < 1e-4) & (np.absolute(res_2) > 1e-10), 1e-5, res_2)
        sum_square_dev[i] = (sum * sum).sum()

    final = np.sqrt(sum_square_dev / length)
    return final

multi = 2
length = 20
basis = sma_calc(source=close, length=length)
dev = multi * stdev(source=close, length=length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev

multi = 2
length = 20
basis = sma_calc(source=close, length=length)
dev = multi * stdev(source=close, length=length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
datetimes = pd.to_datetime(candles[:, 0], unit="ms")

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=datetimes,
            open=candles[:, 1],
            high=candles[:, 2],
            low=candles[:, 3],
            close=candles[:, 4],
            name="Candles",
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=datetimes,
            y=upper,
            name="upper",
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=datetimes,
            y=basis,
            name="bases",
        ),
        go.Scatter(
            x=datetimes,
            y=lower,
            name="lower",
        ),
    ]
)
fig.update_layout(height=600, xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```